# Vim current line to end of block

Tags: vim

I am trying to figure out how to search/replace from current line to end of block and don't understand why my command

```
:.,}s/a/b/g
```

Not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, you have options!

- If end of block means next paragraph then you can use the `'}` mark in your command. e.g. `:,'}s/foo/bar/`. See `:h '}`
- If end of block means to the ending `}` character then you can do as @Dyno Hongjun Fu suggested and use visual mode + a motion. e.g. `v]}:s/foo/bar`. See `:h ]}`
- You can also use a search in your range for a range that doesn't line up directly with any Vim motion. e.g. `:,/baz/s/foo/bar`. See `:h range`
- When in doubt just use visual mode.

Answer (score 4):

here is the [range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#[range]) doc, it seems `}` is not supported there.

as an alternative, you can first visual select with `v}` then do your replacement with `:'<,'>s/a/b/g`